# Magento 2 rest api Consumer is not authorized to access %resources<

Tags: rest, ionic3, magento2

I want to get the products from magento 2 that is in my localhost. but when i put /rest/V1/products? it gives me

```
<response>
<message>Consumer is not authorized to access %resources</message>
<parameters>
<resources>Magento_Catalog::products</resources>
</parameters>
</response>
```

i have made roles and also integration. i don't know how to access these resources. i have to get these products in my ionic app

Comment: have you generated a token and included it in the request?  it would be useful if you would show the complete call you are attempting

Comment: I am trying to get json object in browser by url

Comment: I am writing this in the URL:http://localhost/Magento/rest/V1/categories and it is giving me" Consumer is not authorized to access" I don't know how to acess the json of this page. could you tell me the process how i can access products in json object by url. I am running the store on my local host and I want to get http url to get access to products .so that i can make get http request in my ionic app. In short i want to load the products in my magento store to the mobile app in inonic

Comment: answered below for you

Answer (score 0):

That error is fairly self explanatory - you haven't authenticated.

Here's an example of how to authenticate with an admin user and fetch products using curl;

```
// Fetch the user auth token
$userData = array("username" => "USER", "password" => "PASS");
$ch = curl_init("http://DOMAINNAME.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);

// Now use the token to get all products
$ch = curl_init("http://DOMAINNAME.com/index.php/rest/default/V1/products?searchCriteria");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

// Here are the results
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: how could I authenticate the admin user and get products in ionic. currently i am doing this using  this.WooCommerce = WC( {
url: "https://www.pakden****re.com",
consumerKey: "ck_e9276016ccd326848269f22d2a8991d35",
consumerSecret: "cs_a4180889bd9e0a9460eafeab476b4",
wpAPI : true,
version:"wc/v2",
queryStringAuth: true
This method is for wordpress . i don't know how could i do this for magento